# 500 error on PNG images

Tags: assets, error-message, server

I'm uploading a PNG image into my assets folder and linking to it from my css file - standard stuff, nothing special. However the PNG image is returning with a 500 error in the console and not displaying. When I visit the image directly in the browser I get a lot of numbers and:

```
Template Error

Unexpected character ""
```

[image: Screengrab of error]

I'm working locally with MAMP Pro and I've only recently restored my computer from scratch. I'm wondering whether this is a Craft issue or potentially a MAMP issue. It works fine if I use a Jpg instead or an externally hosted PNG.

This is also happening when I link to it with an img tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host your image assets outside of the templates directory. A more appropriate place for UI assets is in the `/public` directory.

Craft is attempting to parse the image like it is a template, which is causing the `Unexpected Character` error.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise this and built my template structure wrong. Moved assets to the correct place and it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

Try checking file permissions. This happens to me frequently when copying assets from different people on our team.

http://ifmeister.com/mamp-file-permissions-for-a-local-development-environment/

Use devtools or something else to pull up the image in your browser. If you can't open it, there's a file permission problem.

Comment: You may also want to look into hosting your image assets outside of the templates directory. A more appropriate place for UI assets is in the `/public` directory.

Comment: This was the issue. I had the assets folder inside Templates. I've move it out to the root of my public folder and it works now. Make this an answer and I'll mark it correct.